# MERN stack, Mongodb updating all embedded document arrays with this value if they have a certain value

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to updateMany() documents which are an array of documents, if they have a certain value. I am still learning mongodb and I know how to update all documents if they have this value with my new value. The problem I think I am having is that they are an array of documents so I need to go into each document find the field called courses go inside of it and find the document called name and then update it the value of name and I have been trying, but no luck. Also In the request I update the first collection no problem its when I get into the next collection where it does nothing like I already mentioned.

```
 request.body.code = request.sanitize(request.body.code);
            request.body.name = request.sanitize(request.body.name);
            request.body.courses.forEach(course => {
                course.code = request.sanitize(course.code);
                course.name = request.sanitize(course.name);
            });
            let newValues = { $set: {"code": request.body.code, "name":request.body.name } };
            result = await mongoClient.db(DB_NAME).collection("all_courses").updateOne(selector, newValues);
            // Okay now try to update other collection of array documents which isnt working yet
            selector = { "code": "PROG2700"};
            newValues = { $set: {"code": request.body.code, "name": request.body.name } };
            console.log("this is new values");
            console.log(request.body.courses);
            result = await mongoClient.db(DB_NAME).collection("technologies").updateMany(selector,newValues);
```

That is in my server doing the mongodb work and trying to update the documents.

```
let sendString:Object = {
            "id": my,
            "code": edit_Course?.code,
            "name": state_category_name,
            "courses":
                [   
                    {
                        "code": edit_Course?.code,
                        "name": state_category_name
                    }
                ]    
        }
```

That is what I am sending to the server as the request.body

```
{
            "_id": "5fdaa52060689aa159e4122e",
            "name": "Webpack",
            "description": "Webpack is great",
            "difficulty": 2,
            "courses": [
                {
                    "code": "PROG2700",
                    "name": "Client Side Programming"
                },
                {
                    "code": "PROG3017",
                    "name": "Full Stack Programming"
                }
            ]
        }
```

That is what the mongodb structure of each document looks like in the technologies collection that I am having trouble updating. Its the name field I need to update in every document under courses. Could anyone give me a helping hand, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selector` filter doesn't work for the technologies class because the matching `code` field is part of an array named `courses`. To account for this, the filter should look something like this:

```
{ "courses.code": "PROG2700" }
```

This is an example of [querying a field in a document embedded in an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents).

The next step is to update the right document in the array. This can be done in MongoDB using the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) `$`. The update document would look like this:

```
{ $set: { "courses.$.code": request.body.code, "courses.$.name": request.body.name }}
```

In this update document, the positional operator tells MongoDB to update the `code` and `name` fields of the first document in the `courses` array with a `code` of `PROG2700`.

Put together, the update might look like this:

```
filter = { "courses.code": "PROG2700" };
update = { $set: { "courses.$.code": request.body.code, "courses.$.name": request.body.name }};
result = await mongoClient.db(DB_NAME).collection("technologies").updateMany(filter,update);
```

Comment: I feel bad for wasting peoples time, I searched and was not able to figure it out and then I just found what I needed on mongodb docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/. Thanks for your answer though and it is what I did